# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX (react/react-in-jsx-scope)

Tags: android, react-native

I know it's something dumb but i'm relatively new to ReactNative and i don't know how to solve  it

[Print of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCpBJ.png)

Comment: Add `import React from "react"` at the top of the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.